# Saying to no to a command in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I am executing a terminal command inside of a for loop in Jupyter Notebook. However, the command doesn't run because you need to enter y or n after running it. I have tried adding a -y to the end, but that doesn't help. I also tried adding a ! y after but that didn't help as well. I am not getting an error though.

`! python3 nii2png.py -i /Users/coder/Desktop/Training_Data/HGG/HGG1.nii -o /Users/coder/Desktop/Training_Data_Output/HGG`

Then it returns "Would you like to rotate the orientation? (y/n)", but no prompt to enter it.

I would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: What do you mean by "no prompt to enter it"? Is "Would you like to rotate ..." not a prompt? What happens if you just press y and the Enter key?

Comment: In general, a well-designed program will only interactively prompt the user when its stdin is connected to a TTY. If this program _isn't_ well-designed (and prompts on stdin regardless with no means to override that behavior), that's something you can and should submit a patch to its maintainer about.

Comment: ...so: go into `nii2png.py`, find the code generates that prompt, change it to only do so if `sys.stdin.isatty()` is `True`, and you're done.

Comment: (Sure, there are other approaches -- you could pipe the program stdout from something like `yes` -- but those are just hacking around the issue as opposed to fixing it).

Comment: you could check source code and remove this prompt or add code for option `-y` which skip this prompt

Comment: i was able to fix it, but thank you for the help. I just deleted the part that was asking for the prompt in nii2png.py